# How can I avoid the Windows _exec* and _spawn* functions splitting arguments at spaces?

Tags: c++, windows

While using the _execv() function in a C++ Windows console program, I found that the arguments are split at spaces, with each substring becoming a separate argument in the arguments list of the exec'd program. Presumably, this is not happening until after that program is found, as it is being found even when the program path argument contains spaces.

I have written a pair of programs that demonstrate the problem. The same thing happens with _spawnv(), and also if I modify the calling program to use wchar_t arrays and _wexecv().

I am building the examples as either x86 or x64 windows console application projects, using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows 10. How can I avoid this problem while using one of these functions?

```
// Calling program

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <process.h>

int main()
{
    const char program[] = "C:\\Users\\dummy\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\execTest\\x64\\Debug\\testCalled.exe";
    const char* arguments[] = { program, "Hello   World!", nullptr };   // Note the multiple spaces

    for (int a = 0; sizeof(arguments) / sizeof(*arguments) > a && arguments[a]; ++a) {
        std::cerr << "Caller: " << a << " = " << arguments[a] << '\n';
    }
    std::wcerr << '\n';

    auto rc = _execv(program, arguments);

    perror("Exec fail ");
    std::cerr << "return code " << rc <<'\n';
    return rc;
}

// Called program

#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char** argv)
{
    for (int a = 0; a < argc; ++a) {
        std::cerr << "Called: " << a << " = " << argv[a] << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}

Output:
Caller: 0 = C:\Users\dummy\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\execTest\x64\Debug\testCalled.exe
Caller: 1 = Hello   World!

Called: 0 = C:\Users\dummy\Documents\Visual
Called: 1 = Studio
Called: 2 = 2017\Projects\execTest\x64\Debug\testCalled.exe
Called: 3 = Hello
Called: 4 = World!
```

Comment: There is generally a way to get the whole command line without parsing if you need to do it yourself. But better to stick to standard conventions like putting quotes around parameters that shouldn't be split.

Comment: just use `execl` instead

Comment: In my example adding **double** quotes to the arg `"\"hello world\""` worked. However i do not think that this is a generic solution.

Comment: (Nit) following failure and return of `execv`, [`std::_Exit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/_Exit) should be called instead of `return` because the behavior is undefined if one of the functions registered using [`std::atexit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/atexit) calls either `exit()` or `longjmp(3)`.

Comment: @Serge Thanks - I had tried single quotes without success. It also works for argv[0], so long as I use the unquoted string as the program argument to _execv. As you say, it's not a generic solution (if the arguments contain double quotes), but it is close to being usable.

Comment: @Serge If I have to, I can pass a double-quote thus: "\"Hello \\\" World!\""

Comment: @Slava _execl seems to have the same problem, except that neither \\\" nor \" works as a way to pass a double-quote within an argument. Also, I don't know the number of arguments at compile time.

Comment: Using the `_wexec*` family of functions (or `_P_OVERLAY` mode with `_wspawn*`) in Windows is generally a bad idea, especially for console applications (the default link target for the `[w]main` entry point). NT has no equivalent to the `exec*` family implemented for Windows processes, so the CRT simply spawns a new process and exits the current process. If a console-based shell is waiting on the current process, it will resume its standard I/O REPL, and now we have a mess on our hands, with two processes writing to the console and competing for access to console input.

Comment: @eryksun That is a valid point, but as the issue also exists for the _spawnv family of functions regardless of the mode, I have modified the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(edit: avoid using `_execv` in Windows as explained in comments)

To fix the usage for `_execv`, set the first argument to the exact path. Then modify the second parameter (`arguments`) so the path name is in double quotes (as well as other arguments which are broken with blank space):

```
char program[] = "c:\\foler name\\path name.exe";

char *arguments[] = { 
        "\"c:\\foler name\\path name.exe\"",
        "\"(x 1)\"", 
        "\"(x 2)\"", 
        nullptr 
};

_execv(program, arguments);
```

Now the recipient should see `argv[0]` as `"c:\\foler name\\path name.exe"`, `argv[1]` as `"(x 1)"` ...

You can also use `CreateProcess` and put program name and arguments in one line.

```
#include <windows.h>
...

std::string cmd;
cmd += "\"c:\\folder name\\path name.exe\" "; //<- add extra space manually
cmd += "a "; //<- add extra space manually
cmd += "b c d ";
cmd += "\"Hello   World!\" "; //<- add extra space manually

STARTUPINFOA si = { sizeof(si) };
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
CreateProcessA(0, cmd.data(), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
//* if cmd.data() is not supported then copy to char buffer

//optional: wait until process is finished
//WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
//CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
//CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
```

See also
[Parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/17w5ykft(v=VS.85).aspx)

Comment: The CRT's [`[w]spawn*`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/spawn-wspawn-functions?view=vs-2017) family (of which `[w]exec*` is the dysfunctional `_P_OVERLAY` mode that never should have been implemented) already uses the `lpApplicationName` parameter of `CreateProcess`. For the [p]ath-search versions, it searches the `PATH` environment variable. Anyway, we can use the `lpCommandLine` parameter by itself if the application-path is in double quotes. That's the one and only part of command-line parsing that's guaranteed to work; everything else is up to the program.

Comment: @eryksun That's a good point. I changed the usage for `CreateProcess`. I managed to get it to work for with `_execv`, not sure if it's worth it though, since `_execv` is Windows specific anyway.

Comment: `exec*` isn't specific to Windows (but `_wexec*` is). If you mean the leading underscore prefixed on the name, that's for strict ISO C/C++ compliance, since `exec*` is a POSIX function family. You can use the name without an underscore by defining `_CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE`. That said, the presence of `exec*` serves mostly as a trap for unsuspecting POSIX developers who have to port programs to Windows. It should be avoided in most cases since all the Windows implementation can do is spawn a new process and exit the current process.

Answer (score 1):

On Unix-like systems, `execve` is the system call that allows a program to erase itself with a different one, which receives **separately** the arguments, and the `exec` family function directly call it.

On Windows, the system API define the `CreateProcess` function which uses the name or path of the new program (as `execve` does) and a single command line which is built by joining the parameters of `exec`.

That means that you have to enclose the parameters containing spaces in explicit double quotation marks. So the Windows way is indeed:

```
const char* arguments[] = { program, "\"Hello   World!\"", nullptr };
```

The C standard does not define an `execv` function, it is only defined in Posix and Windows, despite trying to be compatible is not a Posix system, so caveats are to be expected...

Comment: Note that this rule for double quotes in the command line is up to individual programs. It's the case for most programs, which use the `argv` parameter of VC++ `[w]main` or `CommandLineToArgv`. Some programs may also accept single quotes, especially if they take other commands as parameters (e.g. schtasks.exe), but generally it's not well documented.

Comment: @eryksun: you are right. I found the double quotes in Microsoft documentations... for VC++! But programs can decide to parse the command line by themselves without using the crt library ([w]main) nor `CommandLineToArgv`. But I have identified no of them...

Comment: I'm sure you use one such command frequently, either directly or indirectly: `cmd.exe /c [command(s)]`.

Comment: For single quotes, an easy example is WSL bash in Windows 10: `bash -c 'echo $0 $1' spam eggs`. Without the quotes the command would just be `echo`, and the rest are parameters 0-3. With the quotes the executed command is `echo $0 $1`, and "spam" and "eggs" are parameters 0 and 1.